# JS : How to pass value from module file to main file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm newbie to js main file importing modules.

I'm triyng to pass "results" value from getdata.mjs module to geolocator.mjs "returnedData" with following code :

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Geolocator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-mod-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/geolocator.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="geolocatorAnchor"></div>

    <script src="./libs/jQuery-2.2.4-core-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/jquery-ui-1.11.4-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="./modules/getdata.mjs"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./geolocator.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gelocator.mjs :

```
import {GeolocatorLayout} from "./modules/layout.mjs";
import {GetData} from "./modules/getdata.mjs";

/* /// VARIABLES   \\\ */

/* GIS server adress */
let httpsGisServer = <myServer name>;
let proxyiedUrl = httpsGisServer + "/dotnetproxy/proxy.ashx?";

window.document.body.onload = function () {

    const geolocator = new GeolocatorLayout('geolocatorAnchor');
    geolocator.init();

    const dataStreetsUrl = httpsGisServer + "/php2apps/rues/PDOdataRuesINSbilingual.php";
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    const getdata = new GetData('GET', headers, 'cors', 'default', dataStreetsUrl);

    let returnedData = getdata.requestFromParameters();
}
```

getData.mjs

```
class GetData {
    constructor(method, headers, mode, cache, request) {
        this.method = method;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.cache = cache;
        this.request = request;
    }

    requestFromParameters() {
        const options = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: this.headers,
            credentials: "same-origin"
        }
        async function fetchData(url) {
            try {
                let fetchResult = fetch(url, options);
                let response = await fetchResult;
                let results = await response.json();
                return results;
            } catch(e){
                throw Error(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData(this.request);
    }
}
export {GetData};
```

I can return correct array values within "results".

I do clearly understand that I must let a "delay" in geolocator.mjs in order to the async functions from getdata.mjs to be executed and then sets the value back to "returnedData" but I don't understand how ...

I've tried with async functions but I'm clearly doing it wrong.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `let returnedData = await getdata.requestFromParameters();`? You will probably have to modify `onload` like this `window.document.body.onload = async function () {`

Comment: You're pretty close...I think you're missing a `return` when you do `fetchData(this.request)` in `requestFromParameters`. You probably want to return that promise.

Comment: both of the above comments combined :D

Comment: @mlibby : Yes, already tried it, but no luck.

Comment: @David784 : A return is placed in the try/catch of the fetchData(url) async function

Comment: @Kzone yes, but when you invoke `fetchData` you don't do anything with the return value. So the Promise is discarded at that point. You would need to return the Promise so that `requestFromParameters` will have a return value as well, if you want to be able to make use of it.

Comment: @David784 : Thanks for showing me the way, it helped too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your async function, `fetchData`, but then you are completely disregarding the result. Did you mean to `return fetchData(this.request)`? Then, your `returnedData` variable will be a promise for the data, which you can either `await` for like this if it itself is in an async function:

```
let returnedData = await getdata.requestFromParameters();
```

Or you can `.then` the promise:

```
let returnedData;
getdata.requestFromParameters().then(value => {
    returnedData = value;
}
```

Then the callback, `values => ...`, will be run when your async task completes.

[More info on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the problem. So, I've tried an async function to allow "getdata.requestFromParameters()" to end in order to get the value of "results". As this doesn't work, I've tried the second way with .then() but no matter what I do, the returned value from module getData.mjs is always undefined.  I've checked with debugger if the scripts runs in proper order, to see if there was no mismatch in the sequence but everything seems fine.